# How to check logical operator inside the string or Convert string to code in Java

Tags: java, android, string

I have little confused with check the logical value true or false here. Sorry, I am just growing in java.

IF

```
if(28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30){
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

result print OK in output. but i have actual value is like this:

```
String value="28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30";
```

if i do same thing above like this

```
if(value){
System.out.println("OK OK");
}
```

value doesnot recognize . How do i check above value string . Do you have any idea please sharing with me? i am very new .

**Edit:**  I followed by @suren's answers. Actually getting not error in java with using android getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`.

**Used Java version: 1.6.0**

java:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
public class TEST {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String log="28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30";
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
          Boolean result = (Boolean) engine.eval(log);
          if (result) {
            System.out.println("OK OK");
          }
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

In ANdroid:

```
 import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
    import javax.script.ScriptException;
    public class TEST {
public static boolean checkValid(String pstring) {

     ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
          Boolean result = (Boolean) engine.eval(pstring);
          if (result) {
            System.out.println("OK OK");
            return true;
          }else {
              return false;
          }
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return false;
}
}
```

and call in Main:

```
public class EditBox extends LinearLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {
String v="28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30";
  Log.i("Type", "=="+TEST.checkValid(v));
}
```

Getting error, **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager**

I am also trying to using javacomplier:

```
String value="28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30";
 JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
     int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null,value);
     if(compilationResult == 0){
    System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    }else{
 System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
       }
```

but here i got: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

***Final Edit(Working):***

```
 Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
    try{
        Object obj = interpreter.eval(inputstring);
        if (obj.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

            return true;
        }else{

            return false;
        }
    }catch (EvalError e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need a parser or evaluator which evaluates a given String of logical operations to Java.

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages

Answer (score 4):

One of the simple possible solution using ScriptEngine class and evaluating the string expresssion as a javascript string

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
try {
  Boolean result = (Boolean) engine.eval("28 >= 25 && 28 <= 30");
  if (result) {
    System.out.println("OK OK");
  }
} catch (ScriptException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also consider other java based expression language libraries [Link](http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages)

Comment: Thanks, it is prefect answers. it works fine.

Comment: OK, but be aware that it expects a Javascript expression, not a Java one.  Also, be careful about putting user input into this engine - users can do malicious things with this.

Comment: This is simple solution to solves given expression. This solutions works for Javascript expression. But be careful while using user inputs as @David Wallace mentioned.

Comment: try to implement but getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` . Do you know this exception, why this comes??

Comment: Which java version you are using?

Comment: using java version is 1.6.0

Comment: if i use this, then any library file need for java 1.6.0.

Comment: No it should work without anything. i have java 6 but its working fine for me. i could not find any reason for the exception what you are getting.